# Azure functions in Java - Get remote address IP

Tags: java, azure-functions

I'm looking for a solution to get the remote IP address in an Azure function in Java. The headers from the HttpRequestMessage contains only the host.
I've found a solution for .NET but as usual, more difficult for Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the IP from the request header **x-forwarded-for**:

```
@FunctionName("test")
public HttpResponseMessage getConfig(
    @HttpTrigger(
        name = "request",
        methods = {HttpMethod.GET},
        route = "test",
        authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS
    ) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
    ExecutionContext context
) {
    // Prints all headers
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : request.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
        context.getLogger().info(header.getKey() + " - " + header.getValue());
    }
    // Prints the header containing the IP address in the format ip:port
    context.getLogger().info(request.getHeaders().get("x-forwarded-for"));
    
    ...
}
```

Note that the IP address comes with a port attached. Ex:
123.123.213.213:88999

So you just need do proccess the string to remove the port portion.

NOTE: the *x-forwarded-for header* only exists in the real Azure Functions environment. If you test it in your local environment you will not find such header.